# Carbon sometime return wrong time when have many request to server

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //
    $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
    if(isset($user) && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
      $user->update(['api_token' => str_random(16), 'api_token_lifetime' => Carbon::now()->addHour() ]);
      $profile = $user->profile->toArray();
      $profile['token'] = $user->api_token;
    return response()->json($profile);
    }
    else return response()->json(['Message' => 'authentication mismatch'],401);
}
```

When i send mass request to test my API (500ms / request) , api_token_lifetime return wrong time .
Ex: 
Time server : 6:00AM 24/12/2017
api_token_lifetime : 2:00AM 24/12/2017

Comment: did u checked timezone in config/app.php?

Comment: Define sometimes.